# mysql: running an insert based two other row's value

Tags: mysql, accounting

I have a table with columns: debit, credit, debit_balance, credit_balance, and amount. Debit and credit each pertain to specific accounts.

Each time I add a new row, I want the debit_balance and credit_balance to be assigned based on the account's previous balance.

```
INSERT INTO `ledger` (`debit`, `credit`, `debit_balance`, `credit_balance`, `amount`) 
VALUES ('1', '3', 
(SELECT debit_balance FROM `ledger` WHERE `debit` = '1' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1) + 5, 
(SELECT credit_balance FROM `ledger` WHERE `credit` = '3' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,1) + 5,
'5')
```

Where debit's account is 1, credit's account is 3, and the amount I want to change is 5.

When I run the query, mysql gives me a `Every derived table must have its own alias` error.

Comment: What is it about that query that isn't doing what you want?

Comment: I get a `Every derived table must have its own alias` error, but I'm running the queries in a value assigning position, versus a join where this would make more sense.

Comment: That schema seems super strange, which is likely part of your problem. A true ledger table has no "balance" column, the balance is simply the sum of the credits minus debits. Have you tried adding aliases to your `ledger` references? `AS ledger_a` for example.

Comment: The general ledger in most accounting software include the balance of the account after every transaction.

We use the balance column so that we don't have to recalculate every time we look at the ledger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `SELECT` query to provide the values to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO ledger (debit, credit, debit_balance, credit_balance, amount)
SELECT 1, 3, l1.debit_balance + 5, l2.credit_balance + 5, 5
FROM (SELECT MAX(id) AS debit_id FROM ledger WHERE debit = 1) AS maxd
JOIN ledger AS l1 ON l1.id = maxd.debit_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS credit_id FROM ledger WHERE credit = 3) AS maxc
JOIN ledger AS l2 ON l2.id = maxc.credit_id
```

Comment: tThis totally worked! Trying to upvote, but SO won't let me. Thanks, Barmar!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the guidance here!